# Can you get the themes options page to turn on/off which custom post types are registered?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-options

I have a theme that is being used for a multisite installation that will be used by 6 sub-brands of an organization. Each sub-brand will only require some of the custom post types set up by the theme – thus I would like to hide the ones not needed.

The theme has an options page where I can set a variable to state which brand is using the theme. Can I then get the functions.php to check what the variable has been set to and then register post types depending of this variable?

eg. If the brandX then register post types A & C, if brandY then register post type B, if BrandC then register none.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a dynamic variable value of the brand, then you can load wanted CPT.

Inside function.php
Create a link to your new function "remove_cpt_multisite". 
Ex:

```
// Remove menu items for users 
include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/functions/remove_cpt_multisite.php');
```

The template itself (remove_cpt_multisite.php) :

```
<?
       add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
       function my_remove_menu_pages() {
          $my_brand_variable = "get your variable";
          // According to the value add wanted CPT with a switch
          switch ($my_brand_variable) {
             case "brand1":
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/functions/register_cpt_1.php');
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/functions/register_cpt_5.php');
             break;
             case "brand2":
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/functions/register_cpt_1.php');
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/functions/register_cpt_2.php');
             break;
          }
      }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I can't see to get the function.php to see the variable thou. I'm having to use a bought theme, so I'm having to hack around what's already there. When I set the variable in the themes options I can see it frontend: `echo $_mc_option['brand_choice'];`. The dev seems to call his theme option variables by the following method, which I can't duplicate: `global $_mc_option;
 if ($_mc_option['brand_choice']) {
  $my_brand_variable = $_mc_option['brand_choice'];
 }`

Comment: Have you tried to add my function at the end off the function.php template?
Otherwise, if you have the information saved inside your theme option, simply get this information directly from the database.

Comment: Note: global $_mc_option; will difine globally the variable within the scop

Comment: I've got the function as the last thing in the function.php, but it still doesn't pull in the "brand_choice" variable or if it does it's not passing it on tp $my_brand_variable. I have it set up as follows: `add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() { global $_mc_option; if ($_mc_option['brand_choice']) { $my_brand_variable = $_mc_option['brand_choice']; } switch ($my_brand_variable) { case "brand1":`

Comment: Alternatively how would I get the info directly from the DB, as it's a multisite there are 6 sets of tables?

Comment: Right, I've not got $my_brand_variable to show from end too. Within the theme-options.php I've added `global $my_brand_variable; if(isset($data['brand_choice'])){ $my_brand_variable = $data['brand_choice']; }` and I can echo it in to the header.php and it will change as I chance the option to a different brand. Still can't get it into function.php

Comment: I can also see $my_brand_variable in the backend. I have added an echo into the "my_remove_menu_pages" function and this now shows the variable at the top of the page.

Comment: I have also tried: `add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
 global $my_brand_variable; 
   if ( $my_brand_variable == 'brand1' ) {
    register_post_type( //etc`

Comment: okay so the if statement is working, it's just not doing the register_post_type bit from within the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Right I have come at this from a different angle. I registered all the posts as normal. And then depending of the variable set it will remove the menu from the backend.

```
function remove_menu_items() {
    global $brandChoice; 
    if ( $brandChoice == 'brand1' ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cpt1' );
    } else if ( $brandChoice == 'brand2' ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cpt2' );
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items' );
```

This is now working as I hoped, As I change the brand in the brand variable in the themes options and then load any other backend page the menu structure changes to only show the CPT I want to see.